# How to create an offline copy of Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-exchange

Our country's Internet is going to be national! So accessing websites like Stack Overflow, Google, YouTube, etc. is going to be blocked.
I am a programmer and my life depends on these websites (especially Stack Exchange websites).

I searched a lot and I found some datasets for Stack Overflow, but after the global Internet get blocked, we don't have any access to [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) and I don't know how to use those datasets!

Alternatively I wanted to download the entire **Stack Overflow** website for offline access using **[wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)** on Windows. But after minutes, the website blocked my IP address because of **too many requests** so the progress terminated.

Is there another way to download Stack Overflow question and answers without the need for SQL Server and just reading an index.html file?

Comment: download the data-dump: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede

Comment: _"Our country's internet is going to be national!"_ Wait what? Is this a hypothetical scenario, or is this actually based on real events?

That said, the data dump by itself isn't very practical... Half of the usability of SO comes from it being indexed by search engines.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes unfortunately thats real...I need a more detailed answer.How can I download full website offline and search through it?Is that possible?

Comment: Besides the data dump, there is no (easy) way to do what you want. As you already noticed, you will be blocked when you issue too many requests. Even if you would be able to download the whole site, I highly doubt that it will be of much use since you don't have a search functionality then.

Comment: I would be really curious which country you are talking about, blocking the whole internet sounds like a very strange idea. You don't have to answer that if it might get you into troubles.

Comment: @BDL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188064/offline-web-search

Comment: @BDL Does this apps(in the link) work for stack data dumps?

Comment: @BDL Iran probably, they are working on an internet censorship bill

Comment: You can use the data dump and make your own local database. It doesn't have to be a SQL Server.

Comment: Note that the data dump is going to be out of date. Manually scraping isn't a particularly good option. There's 6000 or whatever new questions per day, and with the 10k quota, you simply cannot stay up to date and get everything in time for a shutdown, unless you have a lot of time. If you use the full 10k to get questions and answers, a page size of 100 won't get you 1 million questions, and answers increase the "cost", making that a very unlikely approach. My serious advice is to move somewhere the internet isn't suppressed by a misguided and/or malicious government.

Comment: @Zoe Getting answers to questions which you're not otherwise retrieving does add the SE API quota cost of getting that answer's question (or that answer, but the quota cost is the same for getting a single answer vs. the question the answer is on and all of that question's answers, so it's commonly better to get the entire question and its answers). Also, 10k requests (quota) * 100 questions/request = 1M questions and all the answers on those questions. So, while using the SE API to get the data isn't the right way to go, it is *possible* to do so over many days, but less than a month.

Comment: I believe the [Brave](https://brave.com/) browser has Tor built in. Perhaps you can make us of it.

Comment: Or just use [Tor](https://torproject.org).

Comment: @Scratte  I think one issue is that the web borders will be locked and for something as safe as browsing SO using TOR (or derivatives) would have the users door knocked down by the Thought Police, as we are long past 1984.

Comment: @Scratte I've downloaded Brave and used it for *wget* method . But again , after minutes I've been blocked because of too many requests for stackoverflow.

Comment: I meant that *maybe* it can be used to circumvent the block later on. Not to keep you from getting rate limited. You'll have to download the data dump instead. If you want all the content of Stack Overflow, you'll need to do it in ways that are available, not start something that looks like DoS'ing (Denial of Service attacking) their server.

Comment: @Scratte Access Youtube in our country is denied and we are using that with only VPN . After our internet become national , accessing to VPN is denied too, and related ports will be closed...I'm an 2-year student at university and I want to migrate after my license ends and want to continue learning in another country. But for this 2 years remaining,I need a free internet or at least offline version of key websites for temporary to make my learning successful.

Comment: @Scratte Working with that data dumps is hard also ,although I'm doing my best to work with that .

Comment: Screenscraping needs to be rate limited (and is not feasible for [21,566,539 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)). A 3 seconds pause between each request works fine, at least up to 100 pages. A 15 seconds pause between each works for 1500 pages (retrieval time about 6 hours).

Comment: Are you downloading from [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)? Because the downloads themselves should be easy.

Comment: The data dump is on the order of 100 GB. Wouldn't you run into other limits?

Comment: @Scratte Yes, download itself progressed but  using that data and huge confusing scripts and not an UI to see everything structured is my problem...

Comment: @PeterMortensen No problem for downloading...As I said to Scratte, my problem is working with that data dumps.

Comment: I'm just curious... are you sure they're going to block stackoverflow.com or are you just taking precautions? Will they blacklist specific sites or block everything and only whitelist a few?

Comment: Wouldn't something like (local) [Elasticsearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch) / [OpenSearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSearch_(software)) ([Apache License 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License_2.0)) work? In any case, an offline version of Stack Overflow is an interesting idea.

Comment: @41686d6564 In this country everything is possible :) So instead of seating and watching what problem I will face , I'm trying to save everything for bad days incoming. National Internet is an impossible thing to whole countries  but as you see ,we will face this problem 3 months later...Thats possible because they dont want people to communicate in a foreign app or website. They want to control people!

Comment: I can only think of [Myanmar](https://www.accessnow.org/update-internet-access-censorship-myanmar/), though other candidates are [Russia](https://www.defensenews.com/opinion/2021/08/05/putins-push-for-isolated-internet-will-shift-the-russian-cyber-landscape/) and smaller [Gulf states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_states_of_the_Persian_Gulf). [China's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_China) probably wouldn't change on such short notice.

Comment: *[National intranet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_intranet)* lists Myanmar, Cuba, US, North Korea, Russia, China, and Iran for past, present, and future instances.

Comment: If your primary goal is learning, I suggest that you focus on obtaining books around topics you are interested in. Books are far better source for learning and gaining experience, they will also give you skills needed to help yourself.

Comment: There are copycat  sites already. Try to find as many as you can. Might be worth a new question.

Comment: The best way may be to ask some knowledgeable (require some programming knowledge+money to host a server) people to host a backup site inside the country then access that...  or do it yourself (learn SQL!)

Comment: Aww... that's *sad*. Your country censoring your internet.